# I can not make rewieer/TaskSchedulerBundle for Symfony work

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I am trying to create a central cron controller in Symfony, similar to what does Laravel. I found this great component: https://github.com/rewieer/TaskSchedulerBundle but I can not make it work.

The documentation is for Symfony 2 and I am using 4.3

I tried to adapt what I understood.

**There is no AppKernel.php so I used app/config/bundles.php**

It looks similar to this

```
<?php

return [
    ...
    Rewieer\TaskSchedulerBundle\RewieerTaskSchedulerBundle::class => ['all' => true],
];
```

**Then I created my task class**

```
<?php

namespace App\Tasks;

use Rewieer\TaskSchedulerBundle\Task\AbstractScheduledTask;
use Rewieer\TaskSchedulerBundle\Task\Schedule;

class UpdateDFsize extends AbstractScheduledTask {

    /**
     * Set the Cron Schedule
     *
     * @param Schedule $schedule
     */
    protected function initialize(Schedule $schedule) {
        $schedule
            ->everyMinutes(5); // Perform the task every 5 minutes
    }

    /**
     * Run Update DFsize cron
     *
     * @return string|null  result of the cron or null if fails
     */
    public function run() : ?string {
        //Do some stuff
        return $result;
    }

}
```

**Instead of using service.xml I created a service.yaml**

I added a config suggested in a comment (I lost the link)

```
parameters:

services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.

    #Added per recommendation
    **_instanceof:
        Rewieer\TaskSchedulerBundle\Task\TaskInterface:
            tags: ['ts.task']

    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'

    # controllers are imported separately to make sure services can be injected
    # as action arguments even if you don't extend any base controller class
    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

    # add more service definitions when explicit configuration is needed
    # please note that last definitions always *replace* previous ones
```

**Finally I try to run**

Before you ask, yes, I modified the *path/to/project*

```
php /path/to/project/bin/console ts:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

But nothing happens, I get no response in the console and I do not know how to debug it with xdebugger+phpstorm

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

**To test my cron I created a Controller**

With this, I confirmed that the code was correct

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Tasks\UpdateDFsize;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class CronController
{

    public function __construct() {
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/cron/dfsize", name="index")
     * @param UpdateDFsize $updateDFsize
     * @return Response
     */
    public function updateDFsize(UpdateDFsize $updateDFsize) : Response {

        $response = $updateDFsize->run();
        return new Response($response, Response::HTTP_OK);

    }

}
```

**EDIT:**

The answer from @NicoHaase fits perfectly. However, I needed the cron controller to be executed externally, so I followed this Symfony documentation https://symfony.com/doc/current/console/command_in_controller.html and modified my controller to be accessed externally

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;
use http\Exception;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\BufferedOutput;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class CronController
{

    /**
     * @Route("/cron", name="cron")
     * @param KernelInterface $kernel
     * @return Response
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function runCron(KernelInterface $kernel) : Response {

        $application = new Application($kernel);
        $application->setAutoExit(false);

        //Run the command
        $input = new ArrayInput([
            'command' => 'ts:run',
        ]);

        //Prepare output
        $output = new BufferedOutput();
        $application->run($input, $output);
        $content = $output->fetch();


        return new Response($content);

    }

}
```

Comment: Have you even tried anything for debugging, like printing some debug output? Because 1) your command will only run each five minutes (like at minute 0, 5, 10,...) and 2) you suppress all output by piping it to `/dev/null`

Comment: Obvious question is: Does the task produce any output (in code)? Second thing, you changed the `path/to/project`, but did you execute the command as is ? `>> /dev/null 2>&1` is supressing all output.

Comment: @NicoHaase I created a controller to test task and it works. I run manually in console the task and nothing happend

Comment: @msg I tried with ````>> /dev/null 2>&1```` and without it, no difference

Comment: Please have a look at my answer - additionally, which kind of output do you expect? The given `run` method does nothing - it might possibly return a string, but it does not print anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see what is going on, you can use the command `ts:list`. Does this list the command in question? Then your service definition is fine, and the problem lies within your task.

To check this further, let's inspect your task: by defining `$schedule->everyMinutes(5);`, you specify that it should only run when the current minute is divisible by five. So, if you for example run `ts:run` on 17:03, the task will not execute. If you call `ts:run` on 17:05, it will execute. The cron concept does not save the last execution time and rerun your task after five minutes have elapsed - the other way around, if you call the runner multiple times within that same minute (so before 17:05:59), the task will also be executed multiple times.

While debugging, it might be helpful to skip this part. By not defining any schedule (through leaving this empty), your task will run on each call.

Additionally, how did you check whether the task ran or not? Your sample code does not contain any action to be run, so you could at least add any debug output

Comment: I created a controller to do that

Comment: What does that mean? Which kind of controller did you create, what does it contain? Can you add it to the question by editing it?

Comment: I modified the task to echo the result instead of returning it and changed the minute to my local minuted and the task ran

Comment: @PabloHernández-OtakuPahp that sounds good. Additionally, I've added an idea to check: skip the scheduling part completely to let the task run on each call

Comment: That is good if I only call one cron, but since I want to have many tasks runing in different times, I'll keep the scheduling

Comment: Of course, for production use, you should not skip it - but you can do it while developing, just to check what is happening

Comment: I modified the controller to let the cron be executed externally

Comment: But by calling `run` on that class directly, you bypass all scheduling parts. The scheduler itself checks whether any task should be run (according to the cron settings) and then calls `run` to execute the task

Comment: I didn't call the task run I call the cron service run. I did tests and it only runs if the schedule is met